# Find tangent plane when going through two points at the same time

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Determine the equations for all planes tangential to the surface

$$x^2  + 2y^2  + 3z^2 = 6$$

and containing the points $(6,0,0)$ and $(0,3,0).$

I know how to find the tangent plane of this when it's only one point. But how do I do if it has to go through two points?

Comment: Can you check the equation of the surface? Btw the question seeks you to find equation of the plane that passes through these two points and is tangent to the surface - the points themselves are not on the surface.

Comment: sorry, it should be correct now

Comment: Here's one way to begin: if two points are on a plane, then the vector between those two points must be orthogonal to the normal vector of the plane. This gives you some information about the tangent point

Comment: Take the third point as $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$ which is on the surface. Find normal vector to the plane through these three points. Also knowing the equation of the surface, you can find normal vector to the tangent plane at point $(x_0, y_0, z_0)$. Please edit the question with your effort if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The equation of the tangent plane to the ellipsoid $x^2  + 2y^2  + 3z^2 = 6$ at the point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ can be written as $xx_0+2yy_0+3zz_0=6$. Hence it remains to solve the system
$$\begin{cases}
x_0^2  + 2y_0^2  + 3z_0^2 = 6\\ 
6x_0+2\cdot 0y_0+3\cdot 0z_0=6\\
0x_0+2\cdot 3y_0+3\cdot 0z_0=6
\end{cases}.$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thanks, I managed to do it. The answer is x + 2y +3z =6, however, that's one solution, there is also another solution to this. Two solutions.

Comment: In order to find $z$, you have to solve a QUADRATIC equation which has two solutions.

Comment: Yes of course, I missed that, thanks